# How to change file names by replacing characters?

Tags: python

I've 6000 similar files and their names changed a bit and i don't understand how. So my files now look like this

```
HARPS.2010-10-19T02_24_55.819_e2ds_A.fits
HARPS.2016-01-20T00_38_12.300_e2ds_A.fits
HARPS.2015-11-26T04_30_27.879_e2ds_A.fits
```

So i want to replace the '_' with ':' but not at all places. So basically i want them to look like this:

```
HARPS.2010-10-19T02:24:55.819_e2ds_A.fits
HARPS.2016-01-20T00:38:12.300_e2ds_A.fits
HARPS.2015-11-26T04:30:27.879_e2ds_A.fits
```

How can i do that?

Comment: What places do you want to replace? Also, does the data remain consistent?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question again and i don't think it's going to affect the data. @ThatBird

Comment: Colons are prohibited in the Windows world, as they conflict with drive letter naming convention (C:). There is no such prohibition in Linux. Now, that being said, if you try to copy said file to a Windows system, the results will be "interesting". From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/33c9yf/colon_in_filename/)

Comment: Are you asking how to change filenames, or how to create a new string based on a pattern? Or how to find file names in a directory matching a pattern? These questions either have simple answers, or have already been asked before (or both).

Comment: @qräbnö Actually, colons are not forbidden. It can produce very, very confusing effects though. See [Alternate Data Streams](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs/)

Comment: @PeterWood: OK, you are right, but try to create a new file in Explorer and enter a colon. That will not succeed for the time being.

Comment: But we're using Python, not Explorer.

Comment: @PeterWood: Next point for you. I just wanted to draw attention to this problem.

Comment: Are you on windows? You will have [**trouble**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs/) if you have colons in filenames.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is consistent,

```
import os

# iterate over your files
for fileName in os.listdir():
    newName = fileName[:-13].replace('_', ':') + fileName[-13:]
    os.rename(fileName, newName)

# 'HARPS.2010-10-19T02:24:55.819_e2ds_A.fits'
# 'HARPS.2016-01-20T00:38:12.300_e2ds_A.fits'
# 'HARPS.2015-11-26T04:30:27.879_e2ds_A.fits'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use python's replace function with [count](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) for number of replaces like -

```
str.replace("_", ":", 2) #where 2 is the number of instances of "_" 
# you want to replace in a string
```

Ex -

```
x = "HARPS.2010-10-19T02_24_55.819_e2ds_A.fits"
x = x.replace("_", ":", 2)
print(x) # prints HARPS.2010-10-19T02:24:55.819_e2ds_A.fits
```

Comment: @heemayl I don't understand what you want to say. This is what docs say `If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced`

Answer (score 1):

**Try regex `T(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)` replace with `T\1:\2:\3`**

```
import re

regex = r"T(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)"
subst = r"T\1:\2:\3"

list_test = ["HARPS.2010-10-19T02_24_55.819_e2ds_A.fits",
             "HARPS.2016-01-20T00_38_12.300_e2ds_A.fits",
             "HARPS.2015-11-26T04_30_27.879_e2ds_A.fits"]

for test in list_test:
    print(re.sub(regex, subst, test))
```

Output :

```
HARPS.2010-10-19T02:24:55.819_e2ds_A.fits
HARPS.2016-01-20T00:38:12.300_e2ds_A.fits
HARPS.2015-11-26T04:30:27.879_e2ds_A.fits
```

Comment: Have you tried this? On Windows, you now have [**hidden data**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs/) on a file named `HARPS.2010-10-19T02`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

inp = 'HARPS.2010-10-19T02_24_55.819_e2ds_A.fits'
m = re.search('(^.*T)(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})(.*$)', inp)
if m:
    modified_val = ('%s%s:%s:%s%s' %
       (m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(5)))
```